# Instanciar variáveis tipadas no construtor via reflectionClass

Tags: php

Estou desenvolvendo uma **aplicação** com **URL's amigáveis** e chegou um momento em que não consigo achar saída.

Tenho o seguinte:

```
$constructParams = [];

$reflectionClass = new \ReflectionClass($controller);

$construct = $reflectionClass->getConstructor();

if (isset ( $construct ) ){

    foreach( $construct->getParameters() as $parameter){
    
        $class = $parameter->getClass();
        
        $constructParams[$parameter->name] = $class 
                                                ? new $class->name 
                                                : $parameter->name;
        
    }

}       

$instance = $reflectionClass->newInstanceArgs($constructParams);
```

Esse **código** **instancia** uma **classe** e **popula** seu **construtor**.

Minha dificuldade é que, se algum parâmetro do construtor (caso ele tenha algum) for um **objeto** de uma **classe**, o problema será sanado por:

```
$parameter->getClass();
```

no entanto, se esse **parâmetro** (*que sempre será tipado*), for um **int**, **bool**, **float** ou outa coisa, não consigo determinar seu tipo.

**Exemplo**:

```
public function __construct (Classe $classe, int idade)
```

Já pesquisei de tudo mas nada encontrado!

Em tempo: Se eu não **tipo** os **parâmetros** que **NÃO** são **objetos**, tudo ***funciona bem***.

Mas o *objetivo* é **tipar**.

Comment: Ates de o oferecer uma resposta veja se é o que está procurando: https://repl.it/repls/CadetbluePuzzlingTrigger

Comment: Não amigo. Lá você fez direto! Precisa usar ReflectionClass porque vou apenas lancar os tipos no construtor. Mas quando vou verificar os parâmetros recebidos, cada um deles vem deno de um objeto Class que é o retorno da ReflectionClass.

Comment: Desculpe-me se não me fiz claro. Quis dizer com o exemplo é que o `ReflectionClass` não funciona com tipos primitivos(`integer`, `boolean`, `string`,... )  essa classe só funciona com tipos derivados de `object` então é preciso filtrar o que vai instanciar com `ReflectionClass`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resposta a quem puder ser útil como foi para mim:

```
$constructParams = [];

//Fazemos a Reflexão da function da classe      
$reflectionClass = new \ReflectionClass($controller);

//pegamos seu construtor caso exista
$construct = $reflectionClass->getConstructor();

if (isset ( $construct ) ){

    if ($construct->getNumberOfParameters() > 0) {

        foreach( $construct->getParameters() as $parameter){
            
            $type = $parameter->getType();

            if ($type == null) {

                $parameter->name;

            } else { 

                $type = $type->getName();
                
                switch($type) {
                    case 'bool':
                        $type = (bool) $parameter->name;
                    break;
                    case 'int':
                        $type = (int) $parameter->name;
                    break;
                    case 'float':
                        $type =  (float) $parameter->name;
                    break;
                    case 'string':
                        $type =  (string) $parameter->name;
                    break;
                    case 'array':
                        $type =  (array) $parameter->name;
                    break;  
                    default :   
                        $type =  $parameter->name;      
                    break;                                                                  
                }

            }

            $class = $parameter->getClass();
            
            //instanciamos o objeto no Parâmetro que, obviamente for um bjeto
            //o que não for objeto, apenas repassamos o tipo
            $constructParams[$parameter->name] = $class 
                                                    ? new $class->name 
                                                    : $type;
```